# how can i keep going with the correct direction offset

Tags: flutter, dart

i have the following code

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  const Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Test> createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {

  late Offset myOffset =  const Offset(0,0);
  Timer? myTimer ;
  double dx = 0 ;
  double dy = 0 ;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onPanUpdate: (t){
            myOffset+=t.delta;
            dx = myOffset.dx;
            dy = myOffset.dy;
            setState(() {});
          },
          onPanEnd: (d){
            myTimer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: 100), (_)async{
              myOffset =   Offset(dx++,dy++); // here it depends -- or ++ using sad lazy way :(
              await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100));
              setState(() {});
            });
          },
          child: Transform.translate(
            offset: myOffset,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

in my previous codethere is two Scenario

1- user start to swipe on any direction

2- when pan end i need my timer to keep walking on the last correct direction that user's finger was going to it ..

somehow it working but the problem is with the correct direction .. it is going either bottom right or top left .. it is Not very accurate

how can i handle with this any idea ?

Comment: `DragEndDetails` has `velocity` property, you can use it to detect the vector of swipe movement

Comment: i think it is for the swipe speed ? no?

Comment: and what do you want to do `onPanEnd`? you don't want your red square to follow your finger?

Comment: you can imagine this like tender card swipe .. user make swipe action . and once user leave his finger out the screen ,onPanEnd call my timer to keep the last user direction and go on .. i found many plugins for card swip but i want do it my self

Comment: i am now stack on the correct direction only

Comment: so this is exactly what I said: check `DragEndDetails` docs - it has `velocity` property

Comment: i did exactly what you said .. the result was horrible

Comment: yes but how could it help in Timer?.. here i mean the result was horrible

Comment: i mean the animation is not in correct directions value that i get them from velocity  as what you order me to do

Comment: into onPanEnd function i did the following .. myOffset=  Offset(g.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dx,g.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dy);

Comment: Transform.translate widget acting like rough animation result

Comment: https://gist.github.com/pskink/2ee151f6b596629b45e26e1965d037f3

Comment: hmmmmm .. this is completely difference .. i will never ever understand this if you did not share this awesome link .. it give exactly what i need really deeply thanks pskink

Comment: what is completely difference? it uses `DragEndDetails.velocity` to find out the final swipe position, without it, it would not work at all

Comment: i mean about timer .. while you did not comment on it i thought i am going fine with it